# Do Kendo UI Charts support Smart Labels like Telerik UI Charts do?

Tags: charts, kendo-ui

"Smart Labels" are labels that do not overlap each other.

They are mentioned in the docs: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radchartview/features/labels/smart-labels

My question is about "Smart Labels", which is a Telerik UI feature we decided to use. I need to mirror Telerik UI Charts functionality using Kendo UI Charts and thus "Smart Labels" is a requirement.

Comment: As it's currently written it's hard to understand exactly what your question is. Please expand your question, give some more context, so we can better help you.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no such feature in Kendo UI Charts. You can find a [thread relating to this in the Telerik forums](http://www.telerik.com/forums/bar-chart-category-axis-labels-overlapping-when-their-text-is-long).

Basically what the Telerik representative says is that the feature isn't available and suggests several other solutions:

- Use `categoryAxis.labels.step` / `categoryAxis.labels.skip` options and display only some of the labels
- Use a `categoryAxis.labels.template` and trim the labels to a specific length

Another user preferred making the labels invisible altogether.