# Kendo UI pie chart label overlap

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I'm having issues with getting a kendo UI pie chart to display segment labels in a readable fashion. From reading through various forums etc there doesn't seem to be a known approach to solving this issue? Please see the screenshot and dojo link below

http://dojo.telerik.com/icEHu

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read my answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107679/do-kendo-ui-charts-support-smart-labels-like-telerik-ui-charts-do).

What you're looking for is a feature that exists in Telerik's UI widgets called [Smart Labels](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radchartview/features/labels/smart-labels#smart-labels). Unfortunately, this feature doesn't exist in their Kendo UI widgets.

I suggested several solutions to mitigate the issue but it doesn't solve it completely:

- Use `categoryAxis.labels.step` / `categoryAxis.labels.skip` options and
  display only some of the labels
- Use a `categoryAxis.labels.template` and trim the labels to a specific
  length
- Disable labels altogether (probably not an option)